# XSD: Using Visual Studio xsd.exe not generating fixed/default values from base element set through restriction in the child element

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, visual-studio-2015

What I want to achieve is have a base complex type which defines an Id and then have a child-specific value for that id along with each child having additional child-specific elements. I know this can't be achieved in one block so I defined the base type, then defined another type which sets the Id through restriction, and finally I have a type definition which extends the restricted type by adding some more elements.

The schema validates, but when I use the xsd.exe tool to generate the classes, the restricted class does not set the Id in the code at all, resulting in the Id value not being set in the extended class.

I have defined a base complex element in the following manner:

```
<xs:complexType name="BaseElem" abstract="true">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="ElemId" type="xs:int"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Next, I added a child element which sets the ElemId value through restriction:

```
<xs:complexType name="BaseElemFoo">
  <xs:complexContent>
    <xs:restriction base="BaseElem">
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="ElemId" type="xs:int" final="1"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

Finally, I extend the BaseElemFoo to add some more elements and attributes:

```
<xs:complexType name="ElemFoo">
  <xs:complexContent>
    <xs:extension base="BaseElemFoo">
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="FirstElement" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="SecondElement" type="xs:string" />
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="FirstAttribute" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:attribute name="SecondAttribute" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:extension>
  </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

After running xsd.exe (parameters /c and /n) to generate classes for the elements of this type, the ElemId is never set to 1 and the BaseElemFoo inherits from BaseElem, but is empty.

Is there a way to make xsd.exe generate the class from ElemFoo with ElemId value set to 1?